# jQuery Plugins Not working in Richfaces 4

Tags: jquery, plugins, richfaces

I'm trying to create a modal popup in jQuery in JSF 2.0 / Richfaces 4 Application. jQuery works fine as is, say `$('#myDiv').css.` But jQuery plugins fail like **`$.blockUI();`**
I get the error message, the object does not support his property or value.

jQuery Version : 1.4.4

Thanks,
SKR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked
1.The jQuery plugin was put into WebContent\resources folder
2.The plugin was included using  into the body of the page **NOT** the head.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link: 
http://community.jboss.org/message/576568#576568

jQueryPlugin component. Currently only available for RF 3.3.3 as a sandbox component and not RF 4 so probably doesn't help you much now.

A possible workaround taken from this [thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/159796?start=0&tstart=0) that led to the jQueryPlugin component would be:

> RichFaces 3.3.3-Final ship with jQuery 1.3.2. When you include
>   rich:jQuery component in your page the automatically jquery.js script
>   is being loaded. If you want to use custom plugins then you need to
>   include that rich:jQuery component and load your plugin from within
>   body but not from head, cause you don't have any guarantee on order of
>   scripts there.

I know it is based on RF 3.3.3 but I think the same applies for RF 4. The thread has some more helpful information that is worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ross. I'm still unable to make it work, still the same error message.

Comment: just on a side note are you using the $ alias for jquery? Since RichFaces use other js libraries that use the $ symbol you need to use jQuery in place of the $ symbol as well as tell jQuery to not use the $ symbol by specifying jQuery.noConflict() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict)

Comment: Afaik All JavaScript is now based on jQuery in Richfaces 4. Normal jQuery code works fine but not jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

But to clearly maintain the clean code, I recommend to use your own variable such as jQuery or myJquery instead of $, because rich-faces uses this as different variable and you may have conflicts in future for maintainability.